# Replacing special characters with underscore doesn't work in apex. Works in Javascript

Tags: regular-expressions

Replacing special characters with underscore in apex or trigger.I am using below things but getting error.

```
string groupname=(gr.name).replace(/[^A-Z0-9]+/ig, '_');
```

Error: expecting a right parentheses, found '/'

But working in javascript and java but not in apex trigger.

For testing i have used below code snippets

```
String abc = 'SVP, Customer Service & Support group'; 
string groupname=abc.replace('/[^A-Z0-9]+/ig', '_'); 
System.debug('value of string :::: '+groupname);
```

But it returned me below : SVP, Customer Service & Support group but i want to be returned like SVP_Customer_Service___Support_group

Comment: the regex expression to `replace(..)` has to be an apex string

Comment: can you change it to apex string.Do you mean /[^A-Z0-9]+/ig has to be inside quotes like '/[^A-Z0-9]+/ig'

Comment: For testing i have used below code snippets
String abc = 'SVP, Customer Service & Support group';
string groupname=abc.replace('/[^A-Z0-9]+/ig', '_');
System.debug('value of string :::: '+groupname);
But it returned me below :
SVP, Customer Service & Support group
but i want to be returned like SVP_Customer_Service___Support_group

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Java and JavaScript are completely unrelated to each other. Likewise, Apex Code is a descendant of Java, and is a complete stranger to JavaScript. Java requires patterns and such to be enclosed in a string, while JavaScript treats /.../ constructs as syntactic sugar for a more formal structure (this is closely related to how Perl performs its' regular expressions).

In Java, you set/unset flags using (?...). There is no `g` flag, but you can use the `i` flag for case insensitivity. Also, I should mention that `replace()` is a literal replacement, while `replaceAll()` is used with a regular expression. So, your code should look more like:

```
String groupName = gr.name.replaceAll('(?i)[^a-z0-9]', '_');
```

If you choose not to use the `i` flag, you could also have written:

```
[^a-zA-Z0-9]
```

Comment: Thank You! sfdcfox
I was trying since 2 And half hour.Finally i got the solution.